# Correct Multisite MultiLanguage Approach

Tags: localization, multi-site

I am having a website with 4 languages and has two main sections B2B and B2C.

So the final URLs will look like this:

- @web/b2b/de
- @web/b2b/
- @web/de (b2c uses no indication in the link - is default)
- @web/
- @web/tc

Some articles might be at b2b, some at b2c and some might be at both.

My approach to this is to have two site groups

- B2B
- B2C

and then for each of these categories is to have the site in it's 4 different languages.

Is this approach correct?